# Existe alguma função no R, cujo retorno seja idêntico ao retorno da função SEERRO() do excel?

Tags: r, if

Estou tentando gerar uma função geral, que rode vários modelos de regressão. O problema é que, quando um modelo dá erro, a função principal para. Eu gostaria de usar uma condicional que caso tenha erro, pule para a próxima etapa:

Exemplo: ao tentar rodar um modelo `nls()`, apresenta essa mensagem descrita abaixo, como essa função é uma das que estou testando dentro de uma função geral, ele trava a função neste ponto.

um exemplo, quando eu quero carregar algum pacote, eu normalmente faço assim:

```
if(!require(nome do pacote)){install.packages("nome do pacote")}
```

no meu intendimento é assim: se(não existe esse pacote){ instale o pacote}
por isso eu aqui informo que "!" representaria o "erro".

supondo que eu crie uma função:

```
melhor.ajuste<-function(df,x,y){
n1<-nls(y~x+c/e*x^d,start=....,data=df)
n2<-nls(y~x-b*e^d/log(x),start=....,data=df)
n3<-nls(y~x+a*b/c^x,start=....,data=df)
list(modelo1=n1,modelo2=n2,modelo3=n3)}
```

caso por exemplo a função n2 apresente uma erro qualquer, como exemplo:

```
stop(simpleError("Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) :\n matriz gradiente singular com estimativas de parâmetros iniciais"))
```

minha função não me apresentar valor nenhum, pois houve um erro!

o que eu desejo era algo do tipo:

```
if(!nls(y~x+c/e*x^d,start=....,data=df)){n1=0}else{n1<-nls(y~x+c/e*x^d,start=....,data=df)}
if(!nls(y~x+a*b/c^x,start=....,data=df)){n2=0}else{n1<-nls(y~x+a*b/c^x,start=....,data=df)}
if(!nls(y~x+a*b/c^x,start=....,data=df)){n3=0}else{n1<-nls(y~x+a*b/c^x,start=....,data=df)}
```

alguém sabe de alguma forma de eu fazer isso! o excel faz, pela função SEERRO(), onde seerro(caso tenha erro; faça isso), no meu caso seria, `se(seerro(nls(y~x+a*b/c^x,start=....,data=df);0)==0;n1=0;n1=nls(y~x+a*b/c^x,start=....,data=df))`, ou seja seria uma condicional que identifica erro, dentro de uma condicional.

Deixando claro, que em nenhum momento, meu principal objetivo é descobrir qual é o erro e tentar concertar, pois eu irei aplicar a função em mais de 50 modelos, sabendo que alguns não se ajustam mesmo, por ser matriz singular, por estourar o minFactor, e ou coisa parecida. meu objetivo, é encontrar uma forma de que caso a função apresente erro ele concatene 0 ao objeto, e passe para o proximo modelo.

e ao final me forneça a lista de todos os modelos.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o `try`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez este exemplo artificial, como é dito em um dos exemplos de `help("nls")` no qual é inspirado, possa dar uma ajuda. Mostra como se pode tentar vários modelos e continuar mesmo se houver erros nalgum deles. Para isso, utiliza-se a função `tryCatch` que permite obter o erro, uma lista com dois membros.

Dados no fim.

```
regr <- "a + b*x"
resp <- grep("^y", names(dados), value = TRUE)

fit_list <- lapply(resp, function(y){
  fmla <- paste(y, regr, sep = "~")
  fmla <- as.formula(fmla)
  tryCatch(
    nls(fmla, start = list(a = 0.12345, b = 0.54321)),
    error = function(e) e
  )
})

err <- sapply(fit_list, inherits, "error")
```

Agora podemos ver qual a estrutura do erro.

```
str(fit_list[err][[1]])
#List of 2
# $ message: chr "number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50"
# $ call   : language nls(fmla, start = list(a = 0.12345, b = 0.54321))
# - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
```

E obter o membro `"message"` para cada um dos erros da lista `fit_list[err]`.

```
lapply(fit_list[err], "[[", "message")
#[[1]]
#[1] "number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50"
```

Quanto aos modelos que correram bem, pode-se extrair a informação disponível também com ciclos `lapply`.

```
lapply(fit_list[!err], coef)
lapply(fit_list[!err], AIC)
lapply(fit_list[!err], summary)
```

---

Com um `for`, o código tem algumas alterações mas a chamada a `tryCatch` é a mesma.

A alteração é na forma de guardar os resultados. A melhor maneira é criar previamente uma lista e atribuir a saída de `trCatch` a cada membro dessa lista.

```
fit_list_for_loop <- vector("list", length = length(resp))

for(i in seq_along(resp)){
  fmla <- paste(resp[i], regr, sep = "~")
  fmla <- as.formula(fmla)
  fit_list_for_loop[[i]] <- tryCatch(
    nls(fmla, start = list(a = 0.12345, b = 0.54321)),
    error = function(e) e
  )
}

all.equal(fit_list, fit_list_for_loop)
#[1] TRUE
```

### Dados de teste

```
set.seed(2021)
x <- 1:10
y1 <- 2*x + 3                              # perfect fit
y1eps <- y1 + rnorm(length(y1), sd = 0.01) # added noise
y2 <- 3*x - 2                              # perfect fit
y2eps <- y2 + rnorm(length(y2), sd = 0.01) # added noise
dados <- data.frame(x, y1, y1eps, y2, y2eps)
```

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir, falta o `y` ! mas lembrando que não tenho interesse em capturar erro, gostaria de uma forma de condicional, caso: `if(função(x,...)==erro){NULL} else {função(x,...)}`.

Comment: @JeanKarlos Qual é o erro que dá? Pode por um `print(fmla)` imediatamente antes de `tryCatch`?

Comment: não entedi nada, só comentei que falta o `y` no seus dados, então não consigo reproduzir nenhum código que você postou, para tentar entender o que o seu script faria, e se isso poderia me atender, e apenas lembrei, que eu to pouco me importando para qual é o erro, afinal vou testar mais de 60 modelos, o que eu quero é um jeito que caso, os dados apresente matriz singular, ou que `minFactor` estoure, ou qualquer outro erro que possa aparecer, que ele pule o modelo e passe para o próximo, deixando bem claro, não quero entender o erro!!!!

Comment: @JeanKarlos Com os dados que postei o código encontra o `y`. Mas em relação à pergunta, não podemos dizer como correr todos os modelos apesar dos erros, não há código na pergunta que nos permita saber o que corrigir. Pode editar a pergunta com um exemplo de código e de dados?

Comment: Para rodar seu script eu preciso gerar o data.frame `dados`, para isso na 4º linha você pede y`, para criar o objeto `y1eps`, então dessa forma não consigo rodar seu scripit já que ele se baseia no objeto dados.

Comment: @JeanKarlos Tem razão :(. Era `y1` e `y2` em vez de `y`. Corrigido.

Comment: Finalmente, consegui ter tempo de ver, e sim, meio que faz o que eu preciso, na verdade tenho de usar mais uma condicionante depois kkkk, mas já me atende! Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que o que vc procura é a função try()

```
    try(sqrt('a'), silent = TRUE)
```

Que ignora caso exista erro e não trava o código.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).